# Update Query in Access - CASE WHEN

Tags: sql, sql-update, ms-access-2010, case

I am quite new to SQL code and am still learning.

I have a table Gas_Data in which I have a number of days since a certain event which is DATEDIFF, I need to age band this and I am struggling to write the required coding.

I have tried creating another table as a reference and tried various different coding from examples.

"Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'CASE

```
UPDATE Gas_Data

SET MONTH_BAND =

CASE

WHEN DATEDIFF < 29 THEN '00. Up to 1 Month'
WHEN DATEDIFF BETWEEN 30 AND 60 THEN '01. 1 to 2 Months'
WHEN DATEDIFF BETWEEN 61 AND 60 THEN '02. 2 to 3 Months' 
WHEN DATEDIFF BETWEEN 91 AND 60 THEN '03. 3 to 4 Months' 
WHEN DATEDIFF BETWEEN 121 AND 60 THEN '04. 4 to 5 Months' 
WHEN DATEDIFF BETWEEN 151 AND 60 THEN '05. 5 to 6 Months' 
WHEN DATEDIFF BETWEEN 181 AND 60 THEN '06. 6 to 7 Months' 
WHEN DATEDIFF BETWEEN 211 AND 60 THEN '07. 7 to 8 Months' 
WHEN DATEDIFF BETWEEN 241 AND 60 THEN '08. 8 to 9 Months' 
WHEN DATEDIFF BETWEEN 271 AND 60 THEN '09. 9 to 10 Months' 
WHEN DATEDIFF BETWEEN 301 AND 60 THEN '10. 10 to 11 Months' 
WHEN DATEDIFF BETWEEN 331 AND 60 THEN '11. 11 to 12 Months' 
WHEN DATEDIFF BETWEEN 366 AND 60 THEN '12. 12 to 18 Months' 
WHEN DATEDIFF BETWEEN 546 AND 60 THEN '13. 18 to 24 Months' 
WHEN DATEDIFF BETWEEN 731 AND 60 THEN '14. 24 to 30 Months' 
WHEN DATEDIFF BETWEEN 911 AND 60 THEN '15. 30 to 36 Months' 
WHEN DATEDIFF >= 1096 THEN '16. > 36 Months'
ELSE 'NO_AGE_BAND' END AS UNBILLED_MONTHS 

END


MONTH_BAND
00. Up to 1 Month
01. 1 to 2 Months
02. 2 to 3 Months
03. 3 to 4 Months
04. 4 to 5 Months
05. 5 to 6 Months
06. 6 to 7 Months
07. 7 to 8 Months
08. 8 to 9 Months
09. 9 to 10 Months
11. 11 to 12 Months
12. 12 to 18 Months
13. 18 to 24 Months
14. 24 to 30 Months
15. 30 to 36 Months
16. > 36 Months
```

Comment: What about this is not working?

Comment: Apologies. "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'CASE

Comment: you have two `end` in your query. You should use just one. `.... ELSE 'NO_AGE_BAND' END` and that's it

Comment: And also a bit of logic problem: your `BETWEEN 61 AND 60` this makes no sense given the descriptive text for each option... I guess that this is a copy paste problem?

Answer (score 0):

MS Access uses `switch()` instead:

```
UPDATE Gas_Data
    SET MONTH_BAND = SWITCH(DATEDIFF < 29, "00. Up to 1 Month"
                            DATEDIFF BETWEEN 30 AND 60, "01. 1 to 2 Months"
                            . . .
                            DATEDIFF >= 1096, "16. > 36 Months"
                            1=1, "NO_AGE_BAND");
```

MS Access also prefers double quotes for string delimiters.

Comment: Still getting the same error message... Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'CASE

Comment: @LeeHudspeth . . . This code *cannot* produce that error message because it has no `case`.